# Fancyhdr - Is it possible to have a small table inside header?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, thesis

Ok, I'm trying to create this type of formatting for each of my pages:

[image]

Now, I want to have this on every single page, in the header on the right hand side. I currently have the following:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]

    \begin{tabular}{c}
    safasf
    \end{tabular}
\label{lable:nonlin}
\end{table}

}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Chapter \thechapter}

\begin{document}
  \input{title}

  \chapter{Introduction}
  ...
  
  \chapter{Background}
  ...
  
  \chapter{Conclusion}
  ...

\end{document}
```

I want to have this header, on every page even on the chapter pages. Before, using normal text.. The header does not appear to be on the chapter page.

Could anyone offer any solutions or suggestions please?

Comment: Your example is not compilable because missing statements and documentclass. And the table is a floating one, I am not sure whether fancyheader will do with floats.

Comment: The reason is that `\chapter{}` makes use of `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Comment: Please complete your code to make it compile.

Comment: @Sigur Chapter uses `plain` pagestyle.

Comment: @HarishKumar, but with the option that the first page has no header. Am I right?

Comment: @Sigur Which first page? The chapter page? It uses `plain`

Comment: @HarishKumar, maybe I'm confusing. I remember to had seen some `\thispagestyle{empty}` inside some code of `\chapter` on some class. I'll check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put `tabular` material inside the header. But if you use `table` (which is a float) it won't work. Also the chapter page is given `plain` page style by default. Hence you have to redefine the `plain` pagestyle to be fancy.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    safasf
    \end{tabular}
}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Chapter \thechapter}

\makeatletter
\let \ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
%  \input{title}

  \chapter{Introduction}
  ...

  \chapter{Background}
  ...

  \chapter{Conclusion}
  ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

With colored line:

```
\documentclass[twoside,table]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=0.5in]{geometry}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
    \arrayrulecolor{blue!75}
    safasf \\
           \\\hline
    \end{tabular}%
}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Chapter \thechapter}

\makeatletter
\let \ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
%  \input{title}

  \chapter{Introduction}
  ...

  \chapter{Background}
  ...

  \chapter{Conclusion}
  ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,table]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=0.75in]{geometry}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{%
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{capture}%
}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Chapter \thechapter}

\makeatletter
\let \ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
%  \input{title}

  \chapter{Introduction}
  ...

  \chapter{Background}
  ...

  \chapter{Conclusion}
  ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also use a `minpage` wrapping around the `\includegraphics` for vertical position adjustment if needed.

Comment: Do you not get complaints about multiply defined labels?

Comment: @cfr No. But that label I forgot Thanks.:)

Comment: @Harish Kumar Thanks for the reply. But, how would I therefore put a boarder around the "sfsfsf" and make it right aligned even on the first page? It's kinda confusing

Comment: @user1326876 You want borders on all sides or only below as in your picture in the OP?

Comment: @HarishKumar - Hey, as my graphic suggests, the idea is that it will look just like this but will be in the same location on everypage (i.e top right).. But, I could just use an image, let me try this.. Thanks

Comment: @user1326876 You can use the image itself using `\includegraphics`. If you want to draw it, it is quite possible. What do you say?

Comment: @HarishKumar Hey, I think the image would be a lot better. However, I tried `\fancyhead[RO, LE]{
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test}
}` where the filename is `test` in the same directory, but nothing shows up

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13943/discussion-between-user1326876-and-harish-kumar)

Answer (score 4):

Since this is for all the pages, you could use the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[scale=1,opacity=1,angle=0,color=black]{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\backgroundsetup{
contents={
  \tikz\node[draw,text width=4cm,anchor=south east,inner sep=10pt,outer sep=0pt] 
    {For office use only  \\[10pt] \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}};
  },
position={current page header area.south east} ,
nodeanchor=south east,
vshift=-\pgflinewidth 
}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Chapter \thechapter}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
some text\clearpage some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

The [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package was used to have easy access to the header area.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Harish Kumar's approach, a third option is to define a new environment called `tablehere` that won't float as displayed below.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tablehere}
{\def\@captype{table}}
{}
\makeatother
```

Same idea for images

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{figuehere}
{\def\@captype{figure}}
{}
\makeatother
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tablehere}
{\def\@captype{table}}
{}
\makeatother


\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{
    \begin{tablehere}
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|}\hline
    For office use only  \\[10pt] \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{tablehere}
}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Chapter \thechapter}

\makeatletter
\let \ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
%  \input{title}

  \chapter{Introduction}
  ...

  \chapter{Background}
  ...

  \chapter{Conclusion}
  ...

\end{document}
```